# Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am trying to run jsp page using Eclipse Mars IDE , and I have configured Tomacat 7.0.6 Server. But I am getting a problem saying "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

I tried my best but still I am not able to find the solution.

What should be done to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it helps to remove .snap file located in the directory : `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Answer (score -1):

For that you have to delete the server and runtime environments of the server. For that follow below steps :

1. Right click on the server -> delete it
2. Then click on "No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server"
3. Click on the blue link "configure runtime environments". A box will open.
4. Select server then click on "remove" button in the right side. Then click OK.
5. Click on finish.

Then try to run your project, thats all :)

Comment: Well, as I followed above steps I'm getting error in jsp page saying "the superclass javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet was not found in java build path".      Though I run jsp page and same error I got.

Comment: This error means you have not added "servlet-api" jar file. Add this jar file where you have put other jar files, your problem will be solved. @Nisarg